# Can not extract the values when a user enter an escape character

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, split

Given a string input like this: `Key=Value;key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;` and using the `;` as a separator, and also we can use `\;` in the value to be `;` in the runtime.

The problem comes when a user put an input like this `Key=Value\;key1=value1\;key2=value2\;key3=value3;` when I extract the value it gives us a map like this 1 key (Key) and the value (Value;key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;)

Expecting a map of keys and values. 4 keys (Key,Key1,Key2,Key3) and 4 values (Value,Value1,Value2,Value3)

Constraints:

1. The value can be any string.
2. The value can contain another key. Ex. key=value;key1=value=123; so we have 2 keys and value of the second may includes the first key.
3. The key can be any string.
4. can be any number of keys and value.
5. The value can be empty.
6. we have a list of the keys, but the user might not add all of them.

Tried more than regex, but still not completely getting it right. This is the regex currently using:

`([\\n\\s]*(.+?)=(.*?;?);[\\n\\s]*)`

But can you help with the regex or introduce a new algorithm

Comment: Show me your code™

Comment: `String str = userInputString.replace("\\\\", BACKSLASH).replace("\\;", SEMI_COLON);

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([\\n\\s]*(.+?)=(.*?;?);[\\n\\s]*)", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE)
    .matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
   outputMap.put(matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3).trim()
     .replace(BACKSLASH,"\\").replace(SEMI_COLON, ";"));`

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]
If you allow escaped delimiters (`\=` to be in the key and `\;` to be in the value) then you could use lookbehinds to match the real delimiters:

`\b(.+?)(?<!\\)=(.+?)(?<!\\);`

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WCpmLd/2)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand it, the user is responsible for escaping caracters like `;`. If that is true, wouldn't it be reasonable to require them to escape `\` as well?

So using `\` alone at the end, would cause the input string to be invalid in the same way as using `;` without escaping it. Hence, if the user wants to input `\` it should been escaped the same way as before `\\`.

Comment: yes, we have \\ as an escaped, I am trying to not allow the user to put \ in the value ending. like this one Key=Value\;

Comment: If you explicitly allow ´\;´ to be used to provide the (escaped version) of `;` than i don't see a sophisticated way to distinguish between a deliberate `\;` (hance everything after this is intentionally part of the value) and a misplaced ` \ ` in front of a functional necessary `;`.

In your case, it seems like you would recieve a key (possibly containing an escaped `;`) and a value, that will be a key in it self etc.
I think the problem comes down to:
- You can't prevent and allow escaping `;` at the same time.

If you would allow only one '=' than you could maybe do something about it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that puzzle me in your question, and I regret that you didn't provide any code. For instance, why would you need a backslash before semicolons?

That said, you could try something like this:

```
private static final Pattern RE
        = Pattern.compile("\\s*([^=;]+)=((?:[^;\\\\]|\\\\;|\\\\\\\\)*)\\s*;\\s*");

private static Map<String,String> toMap(String input) {
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Matcher matcher = RE.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }
    return map;
}
```

It works with:

```
    String input = "URL=https://postman-echo.com/post;Method=POST;Headers=Content-Type:application/json\\; charset=utf-8\\;;Body=fileName;Cookies Variable Name=;File Path=C:\\s.png;Response Variable Name=ResponseResult;Status Code Variable Name=StatusCode;Response Cookies Variable Name=ResponseCookies;";
    Map<String,String> map = toMap(input);
```

Result:

```
Cookies Variable Name = 
Headers = Content-Type:application/json\; charset=utf-8\;
Response Cookies Variable Name = ResponseCookies
Response Variable Name = ResponseResult
Method = POST
Status Code Variable Name = StatusCode
Body = fileName
URL = https://postman-echo.com/post
```

Comment: For example I can hava a value like this `URL=https://postman-echo.com/post;Method=POST;Headers=Content-Type:application/json\; charset=utf-8\;;Body=fileName;Cookies Variable Name=;File Path=C:\s.png;Response Variable Name=ResponseResult;Status Code Variable Name=StatusCode;Response Cookies Variable Name=ResponseCookies;`

Comment: In this case the keys are (URL, Method, Headers, Body, Cookies Variable Name, File Path, Response Variable Name, Status Code Variable Name, Response Cookies Variable Name)

Comment: I see.  How about `Pattern.compile("\\s*([^=;]+)=((?:[^;\\\\]|\\\\;)+)\\s*;\\s*")`?

Comment: Or, if you want to escape backslashes: `Pattern.compile("\\s*([^=;]+)=((?:[^;\\\\]|\\\\;|\\\\\\\\)+)\\s*;\\s*")`

Comment: Still includes the next key as a value.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/asPcBX/1

Comment: See my update above

Comment: Can you try this inupt, `URL=https://postman-echo.com/post\;Method=POST;Headers=Content-Type:application/json\\; charset=utf-8\\;;Body=fileName;Cookies Variable Name=;File Path=C:\\s.png;Response Variable Name=ResponseResult;Status Code Variable Name=StatusCode;Response Cookies Variable Name=ResponseCookies;`

Comment: it will show the issue when the url ends with \;

Comment: What's the problem? if you have a \, you must escape it